# Is there a way to detect when a user comes back to your webpage after gong away?

Tags: javascript

Let's say someone comes to my webpage and the content is dynamically updated for him. Then he goes away to play a game or answer a call. Then he comes back to the webpage and I want to update the page's content without him pressing Refresh or Reload or using the meta Refresh.

Is there a way for the browser or page (with Javascript) to know that the person is now back to your website? Specifically, the user selects from his phone's opened browser tabs and tap on yours. When he taps on your webpage, I want to execute some code to update the page. But how does the browser or page knows he's now at your webpage? (It's not about detecting a returned visitor).

Sorry if my question seems unclear.

Comment: page visibility api

Comment: See also [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060008/215552)

Comment: Found the answer to what I was looking for. It's using document.visibilityState. Works when the user is on another tab or goes away to another app and then coming back.